# How to update .sln (solution) file within Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, solution, sln-file

I am clean `build`-ing and `rebuild`-ing the project I am working with and I keep getting errors that is is unable to find the path/folder/filename because I ended up updating the name within file explorer.

I want to open the `projectname.sln` file 
and update the file path manually.

My current workaround is to right click `.sln` file and open with VS Code. Do my edits and then save. 
After saving it causes a trigger to reload in Visual Studio

Comment: How would VS know that you had renamed the folder/file?

Comment: @stuartd that's his point - he wants to tell VS about it!

Comment: Hmm. Not sure there's anything like that. Could the path be stored as an environment variable? Then when you change the path, just update the variable. Could maybe have a little batch file or PS script within the path which updates it with the current directory.

But I'm wondering, why is the path changing so often that this is a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `unload project` by right-clicking on the project.

Once unloaded you can right-click and edit `project.csproj`.

Update the paths that are causing the problem.

Save and reload.